# Visits without cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, cookies

I am trying to add a feature to a Java/Tomcat web-application to follow the users during their visits on a website A through Javascript calls from the pages of A to a server B (B's applications run on Tomcat 7). The server has a different address from the website.

Each time a user opens a page on A a piece of Javascript is loaded from a url on B. The javascript is served on B by a controller method, which calls HttpServletRequest.getCookies() and looks for a cookie with the right name. If no such cookie is found, a new one is created and added to the response through HttpServletResponse.addCookie(). The cookie mentions the path and IP of B, so they are available there.

The Javascript on A will then regularly send Ajax POST calls to B, where cookies are checked.

While this scenario works fine for many users, I still get a large number of Ajax calls from A to B without any cookie. Not only the cookies I set manually are missing, but also the session cookies set by Tomcat on B. I understand some users may have just set their browser to prevent or block cookies, but there seem to be too many empty requests. Despite a thorough inspection of the logs, I could not find any common feature that would explain the lack of cookies.

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you underestimate your users' dislike of being tracked in this way.